# Gnu screen, how to update dynamically the title of a window?

Tags: gnu-screen

I'm trying to improve the aspect of GNU Screen using the screenrc file, I tuned colors, status line, caption and the list of the loaded windows.

The only thing I'm not able to achieve is getting the caption with the current executed command as in the below picture, note the vim caption in the right pane:

[image]

What I currently have is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAOba.png), and what I would like to obtain is having captions (and if possible also hardstatus line) with `|0 less|  1 man` instead of the current `|0 bash|  1 bash`.

How can I do this?

**Update:** Until now the only working solution I found is in [this post](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_set_screen_title) but it doesn't print what I need...

However that is the only working dynamic title I found until now.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033k\033\134\033k${HOSTNAME}[`basename ${PWD}`]\033\134"'`
```

in .bashrc and `shelltitle '] |bash'` in .screenrc. The title is updated with the hostname and the basename of the working directory, but the prompt is completely wrong (it also has a leading space):

```
134134fabio@host10:~$
```

Comment: checkout the updates on the answer

Answer (score 8):

In your `.bashrc` file set your `PROMPT_COMMAND` like this:

**UPDATE**:

```
case "$TERM" in
    screen*) PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033k\033\0134"'
esac
```

**UPDATE**: seems to be a bug with echo built into bash. Solution should be either use of `/bin/echo` or `\0134`. Try:

```
$ echo -e "\134 = \0134"
\134 = \
$ /bin/echo -e "\134 = \0134"
\ = \
```

This is the escape sequence that screen needs to identify which command is being run, and replace the title of your current window.

Then, on your `.screenrc` file, make sure the following lines exist:

```
shelltitle '> |something:'
hardstatus alwayslastline
```

The pattern `search|name` tells screen to `search` your `end-of-prompt` for some string (in this case, `'> '`). The name part, specifies the default shell name for the window. So, when you have nothing but the shell running, you'll see something like:

```
$ something:
```

But when you run top:

```
$ something:top
```

Comment: Almost... Your hint for \0134 or /bin/echo works with my above example, so I can have the caption updated with the string between two escape sequences without having my prompt messed. But I can't still make your example working. My prompt under screen is `${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$` so I'm using `shelltitle '$ |bash'`, is that right?

Comment: thanks, I'm having it work without the `hardstatus ...` line in `.screenrc`, I'm using `caption always ...`, not a screen guru though.

Comment: Note that the `shelltitle` stuff has to actually be in your .screenrc - nothing will happen if you enter it at the screen command prompt, for some reason.

Comment: The `/bin/echo` option isn't portable, the `echo` binary differs between linux and other unices like BSD and macOS. Using the `printf` built-in is likely the better solution.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you could use `tmux` instead of `screen`.  `Tmux` will automatically set the current window's title.